# Returned file is not empty but then empty on the next call

Tags: java

I don't understand why in the first iteration of the for loop below I get returned the file I want, but then if I run it again I get back an empty file. Specifically, on the second iteration, I pass a nonempty file to the `builder` method in the `PrizeStrings` class, but for some reason it skips the condition in the `while` loop. How can `reader` not have a `nextLine()` at that point?

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Euler191 {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrizeStrings tester = new PrizeStrings();

        File start = new File("start.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(start);
        FileHandler handler = new FileHandler();
        writer.write("AA");
        writer.write("\n");
        
        
        writer.write("AO");
        writer.write("\n");
        writer.write("OA");
        writer.write("\n");
        writer.write("OO");
        writer.close();       
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            start = tester.builder(start);
        }
```

```
public class PrizeStrings {

    private ArrayList<Integer> counter = new ArrayList();

    public File builder (File file) throws IOException {
        
        int counter = 0;
        File newFile = new File("biggerStrings.txt");
        
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newFile);

        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String x = reader.nextLine();

            writer.write(x + "O");
            counter++;

            writer.write("\n");

            if (!x.substring(x.length() - 2).equals("AA")) {

                writer.write(x + "A");
                counter++;

                writer.write("\n");
            }

        }

        
        writer.close();
        this.counter.add(counter);
        System.out.println("=====");
        
        return newFile;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Scanner` with a `File` as an argument uses the `InputStream` provided by the file. As you are using the same instance of `File` for all three iterations of your loop in your main method, all three `Scanner`s are using the same underlying `InputStream`. The `InputStream`s pointer will, after going through the file once, be at the end of the file, future attempts to access the `InputStream` will therefore start at the very end. Your `Scanner` will obviously not find another line in this case.

A possible solution is to use a new `File` instance every time and close it in the end:

```
public class PrizeStrings {

// ...
    public File builder (String filename) throws IOException {
    
        int counter = 0;
        File newFile = new File("biggerStrings.txt");
    
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(filename)); 

        // ...

        reader.close();
        writer.close();

        // ...
    
        return newFile;
}
```

Comment: But I assign the returned file to start. Why isn't start changing?

Comment: Hm? your `builder`-method always returns a file object encapsulating the same "biggerStrings.txt" file. What do you expect `start` to be in the end, if not this? But your while loop within `builder` will not be doing anything during the second and third run of `builder` for the reasons explained above.

Comment: What I don't understand is this: I send a file to the ```builder``` method, I operate on this file, make a new file in that method, and send back the new file. I then assign this new file to ```start```. So on the next iteration of the loop, why is the file now being passed to ```builder``` the  same original ```start``` and not the updated one?

Comment: It IS the updated one, but the internal file pointer will be at the end, because it is where  you left it. Closing the scanner should fix this.

Comment: I tried closing the scanner without changing the parameter type of the ```builder``` method, and it didn't change anything. However, changing the parameter to a String did work.
EDIT: actually, it's not working. Now I just keep getting the same file back instead of an  empty file, but this is almost as bad.

Comment: That is a seperate issue. Your writer begins at the beginning of the file, overriting anything already in it. It does not append.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231681/discussion-between-junglemath-and-johannes-h).